# How to exclude a package from a dependency jar(using maven) present in a web project?

Tags: java, maven

I have below dependency in my pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.phoenix</groupId>
    <artifactId>phoenix-server-client</artifactId>
    <version>4.7.0-HBase-1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

The above is for phoenix query server interacaction
        This dependency has org.apache.calcite:calcite-avatica:1.6.0 transitive dependency. The calcite-avatica dependency has jackson-databind(2.1.1) one of its transitive  dependency. So jackson-databind(version: 2.1.1) dependency should be included in classpath of my project. But instead of that, all of the classes in the jackson-databind(version: 2.1.1) are included in calcite-avatica jar. I  have declared jackson-databind( version: 2.7.2) as direct dependency in my pom.xml. 
    I can exclude the jackson-databind(2.1.1) through  tag. .    <  
        org.apache.phoenix
        phoenix-server-client
        4.7.0-HBase-1.1
        
              
                   com.fasterxml./*
                   jackson-databind

But it is not getting excluded since it has been bundled in calcite-avatica:1.6.0 jar. Is there any solution for that. I have tried maven shaded plugin. but in vain.

Answer (score 2):

There are different approaches, none of them is perfect:

- If you don't need calcite-avatica jar, exclude it (with the Maven exclude mechanism.
- If you need some classes from calcite-avatica jar, but not the jackson-databind classes, alter the order in which you declare the dependencies. Because Java can load each class only once, either the classes of calcite-avatica jar hide those of jackson-databind or vice versa.
- Create a "hacked" calcite-avatica jar which does not contain the doubled classes.
- If you really, really need jackson-databind in two different versions, you need try to construct this with the shade plugin, but it is not easy.

Comment: I have created a hacked calcite-avatica jar. @JF MeierI need to know in which case the classes of a dependency jar declared in pom.xml are added to the final jar. For instance, (though I have already mentioned but rephrasing)  calcite-avatica declares dependency of  jackson-databind in its pom.xml But instead of downloading the jackaon-databind jar it is placing the classes in calcite activa jar?

Comment: I need to  include calcite-avatica  jar in my project. I need jackson-databind jar in only one version

Comment: Some people use the maven-shade-plugin to integrate all dependencies into their jar - this causes problems like the one you have above. The usual way is _not_ to do this.

Comment: I am sorry, I usually don't give my email address to strangers. What do you want to discuss that cannot be discussed here?

Comment: I wanted to share my pom.xml and to verify any missing configuration for different plugins.

Comment: Sorry, I don't do private help sessions. If you have a question, please ask it on stackoverflow.